# How do you format a screenplay?

Tags: screenwriting

How do you format a screenplay?

If you can refer me to a good book/website on formatting a screenplay, great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would just go to http://www.imsdb.com/ and look at how the professional screenplays are written for a starting point. Also http://www.simplyscripts.com/the-archives/ is a good resource for a general overview. Also I would read general books on screenplay writing to find the little changes you need to make it get accepted. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in how to format a screenplay I suggest you visit http://www.trelby.org/
Trelby is a very good application for both Linux and Windows which formats your screenplay while you write.
As for the way a screenplay is written and the conventions used, the best way is to take a look at the original screenplays of your favorite movies.
You can find plenty of web sites which provide screenplays in pdf format just by searching "screenplays download" on google.